# find domain of given question. f(x,y)=arcsin( √x- √y/ √x+ √y)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find domain of given question.
> $$f(x,y)= \arcsin \frac{ \sqrt x-  \sqrt y}{ \sqrt x+ \sqrt y}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

$\{(x,y)|x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}-\{(0,0)\}.$